# How to avoid duplicate records adding inside angular for each loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

The below directive code is forming an JSON dynamically. I have to form a JSON without dupicate object names.

Angular Code:

```
bosAppModule.directive('layoutTableCellControlLabelRender',function($compile,$rootScope){
    var layoutTableCellControlLabelObj={};

    var soJSON = {
            entityInfo: {
                entity: "",
                tenantId: "",
                timeStamp: new Date().toJSON().toString()
            },
            collections: {

            }
    };
    var myobj={};
    linkFnTableCellControlLabel=function(scope, element, attributes, controllerCtrl) {
        scope.labelData="NO DATA";

        angular.forEach(scope.pageObject.collections.objectattribute.rowset, function (value, index) {
            if(value.objectattributeid==scope.attributeId){
                scope.labelData=value.objectattributelabelname;
                scope.attributeName=value.objectattributename;
                //$rootScope.$broadcast("NEW_EVENT", scope.attributeName);              
                angular.forEach(scope.pageObject.collections.object.rowset, function (value2, index2) {
                    if(value2.tenantobjectid==value.objectattributeobjectid){
                        scope.objectname=value2.tenantobjectname;
                        if(!soJSON.collections[scope.objectname]) {
                            soJSON.collections[scope.objectname]={
                            "meta": {
                                "parentreference": "***",
                                "pkname": "***",
                                "fkname": "***"
                              },
                              "rowset": [],
                              "rowfilter": []
                             };
                        }

                    }
                });

                myobj[scope.attributeName]="test";
                soJSON.collections[scope.objectname].rowset.push(myobj);
            }
        });

        console.log(JSON.stringify(soJSON));

    };


    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.scope={attributeId:'=',layoutData:'=',pageObject:'='};
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.restrict='AE';
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.replace='true';
    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.template="<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6' attribute-name={{attributeName}} attribute-id='tablecellcontrol.layouttablecellcontrolbindingobjectattributeid' " +
                                            "layout-data='layoutData' page-object='pageObject'><label class='k-label pull-right'>{{labelData}}</label></div>";

    layoutTableCellControlLabelObj.link = linkFnTableCellControlLabel;

    return layoutTableCellControlLabelObj;  
});
```

Using aboeve code i am getting the JSON. In this JSON inside rowset records are duplicated because of loop. But i'm bit confused on this. I need avoid it. It should create only one time.
 Anyone please help me to achieve this. If you need more details on this. let me know.

JSON

```
 {
  "entityInfo": {
    "entity": "",
    "tenantId": "",
    "timeStamp": "2016-04-07T07:25:49.711Z"
  },
  "collections": {
    "Customer29Jan16": {
      "meta": {
        "parentreference": "***",
        "pkname": "***",
        "fkname": "***"
      },
      "rowset": [
        {
          "CuId": "test",
          "Name": "test",
          "Quantity": "test",
          "Rate": "test",
          "Amount": "test"
        },
        {
          "CuId": "test",
          "Name": "test",
          "Quantity": "test",
          "Rate": "test",
          "Amount": "test"
        },
        {
          "CuId": "test",
          "Name": "test",
          "Quantity": "test",
          "Rate": "test",
          "Amount": "test"
        },
        {
          "CuId": "test",
          "Name": "test",
          "Quantity": "test",
          "Rate": "test",
          "Amount": "test"
        },
        {
          "CuId": "test",
          "Name": "test",
          "Quantity": "test",
          "Rate": "test",
          "Amount": "test"
        }
      ],
      "rowfilter": []
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add a plnkr/fiddle

Comment: is it always the same json that is generated?

Comment: @Durendal yes it's generating same

Comment: @NitsanBaleli. It;s hard to create plunker because so many things are required. anyhow i will try to create. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's always the same json but you can probably use [uniqby from lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy) on your `rowset` array.

```
_.uniqBy(json.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset, function (e) {
   return e.CuId;
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kq9gtdr0/22/)

**EDIT**

If you have several customers, you can loop over a customer array :

```
arrayOfCustomers = (Object.keys(json.collections));

for(var i = 0 ; i < arrayOfCustomers.length; i++){
  json.collections[arrayOfCustomers[i]].rowset  = _.uniqBy(json.collections[arrayOfCustomers[i]].rowset, function (e) {
    return e.CuId;
  });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kq9gtdr0/23/

Comment: Object(like Customer29Jan16) will come more, its depends on user and each object will have their own attributes and it may come same attribute name for multiple object,

Comment: uniqBy method in underscore. i need to use angular only.

Comment: It doesn't prevent you using an other library while using angular